# Foldable for Tree type, "value of instance is undefined here, so this reference is not allowed"

Tags: purescript

After defining the following simple tree structure

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

I tried defining a `Foldable` instance for it, only defining `foldMap` and using the `foldrDefault` and `foldlDefault` functions:

```
instance treeFoldableInstance :: Foldable Tree where
  foldr = foldrDefault
  foldl = foldlDefault
  foldMap f Leaf = mempty
  foldMap f (Branch left a right) = foldMap f left <> (f a) <> foldMap f right
```

This, however, results in:

```
The value of treeFoldableInstance is undefined here, so this reference is not allowed.
```

When I define `foldl` and `foldr` explicitly, it compiles. The documentation for this error tells me about laziness, but how does that apply here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This occurs due to the use of `foldlDefault` and `foldrDefault` requiring the very dictionary you are trying to construct, and since PureScript is strictly evaluated, that isn't possible.

Probably the easiest fix here is to try something like:

```
instance treeFoldableInstance :: Foldable Tree where
  foldr f = foldrDefault f
  foldl f = foldlDefault f
  foldMap f Leaf = mempty
  foldMap f (Branch left a right) = foldMap f left <> (f a) <> foldMap f right
```

By eta-expanding the `foldr` and `foldl` definitions, it delays the self reference, as the desugared code becomes something like:

```
foldr = \f -> foldrDefault treeFoldableInstance f
```

So the reference to `treeFoldableInstance` is only evaluated after `f` is passed in, rather than during the declaration of `treeFoldableInstance`.